# Exporting to spreadsheet from JSF 2 Datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi, export-to-excel

Can someone provide some example in which POI is used to export data to a spread sheet from jsf 2 datatable with sort feature? 
Also I have one doubt.Can i use primefaces dataexport tag along with jsf 2 datatable? As I am new to JSF any answer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we are currently using PrimeFaces DataExporter with our datatables. The generated spreadsheets aren't very beautiful but it's really simple to use in a first time. Moreover it's working with filtering and sorting capabilities.

Here is a sample of our PrimeFaces Datatable :

```
<p:dataTable id="volumeListTable" widgetVar="volumeListTableWidget" value="#{volumeController.volumes}" var="volume" 
                                    paginator="true" rows="#{parameters.rowsNumber}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,25,50"
                                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                    rowKey="#{volume.key}" selection="#{volumeController.selectedVolumes}" selectionMode="multiple"
                                    filteredValue="#{volumeController.filteredList}" >

                            <p:ajax ... />

                            <p:column sortBy="#{volume.volumeID}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{volume.volumeID}" > 
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.VolumeID}" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{volume.volumeID}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{volume.volumeStatus}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{volume.volumeStatus}" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.VolumeStatus}" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{volume.volumeStatus}" />
                            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And here is the commandButton for the dataExporter :

```
<p:commandButton title="#{bundle.Excel}" icon="aofxdm-icon-xls" disabled="#{volumeController.volumesNumber == 0}" ajax="false" >
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":volumeForm:volumeListTable" fileName="Volumes" />
</p:commandButton>
```

You can find all information you need in the [PrimeFaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml) and in the [PrimeFaces Userguide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf)

Another method is creating your own method in your backing that will create your spreadsheet on the list / filteredList used in your datatable and download the created file with p:downloader and StreamedContent from PrimeFaces too.

Comment: @Sebastian : Thanks for providing the example. But i need to incorporate export functionality to jsf 2 datatable which uses the tag <h:dataTable>. Will <p:commandButton ...> </p:commandButton> works along with <h:dataTable> ?

Comment: Unfortunately the p:dataExporter only works with primefaces datatable.